# Invalidating an HTML5 cache (manifest) completely?

Tags: iphone, html, caching, manifest, local-storage

I have an iPhone web-app, and I want to know how to force a cache refresh.

My cache manifest is this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
file1.css
file1.js
```

`index.html` is the meat of the application, so I put that in the cache. At this point, I seem to be boned, as I can't figure out how to get iPhone to invalidate the cache. Even going to `Settings > Safari > Clear Cache` doesn't work, although I'd like to be able to control this programatically. Removing `index.html` from the manifest and re-adding it seems to work, but I would have to know that all my clients had a clean hit of the updated manifest.

How do I cache `index.html` and still have it updated when it changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, any change to the manifest will do the trick - and manifests can contain comments starting with #. Just add a random comment and it'll work.

It's a useful property, when I worked on an HTML5 application in a git repository I used to have the manifest automatically regenerated with a comment containing the HEAD hash after each commit so that the changes always propagate to the users.

Comment: My application is trivial, but I could just write a script to add `git log --oneline | cut -c -7 | head -1` to the head of the manifest as a comment. That's not a bad idea.

Comment: To get the commit hash you can also do `git log -1 --format="%h"`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in WebKit Browsers preventing them to reload the website on manifest changes, see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119427)

Have no clue for a workaround except when I call the index.html directly.

No chance for a iPad/iPhone-WebApp pinned to do the job...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use JavaScript to force Safari to reload cached resource files.

According to Apple, modifying the cache manifest file will cause Safari to reload any changed resource files. **But** those reloaded files won't be used by the browser until the user visits the site a second time. That delay can a pain, especially during development.

To force Safari to reload the cache contents immediately, Apple says you [can use this JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html) to manipulate the `applicationCache` object:

```
function updateSite(event) {
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
}
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', updateSite, false);
```